# Creating methods in batch?

Tags: windows, bash, batch-file

Having built simple bash scripts on a linux server, I figure the best thing to do is build a batch script on my local windows machine to make life easier.

I cant find how to make methods in my script? For example my batch file is named brandname.bat (don't want to reveal actual brand name).

I added it to my environment variables and in the command line I can enter `brandname` but what if I want to do `brandname build plugin` or `brandname build app` is there a way to build a method to handle something like that?

Comment: or look at MS Windows Powershell (not an evangelist ;-) Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can accomplish this using `goto` labels.

```
@echo off

if _%2_ neq __ goto %1-%2

echo Usage:
echo "brandname build plugin"
echo "brandname build app"
exit /b 1

:build-plugin
echo Building plugin
goto :eof

:build-app
echo Building app
goto :eof
```

You can also use labels to create subroutines invoked with `call`

```
@echo off

:: func1()
call:func1
:: func2()
call:func2
:: func1(), again
call:func1
:: func3(testing)
call:func3 testing


goto :eof
:: "Function" definitions

:func1
echo function1
goto :eof

:func2
echo function2
goto :eof

:func3
echo function3(%*)
goto :eof
```

Comment: Awesome, most of that looks clear and my style but could you explain some details, example why start off with `@echo off` what is the purpose of that? Secondly why end the function with `goto :eof`. As for the function itseld `:func1` is self explanatory, calling the function and passing in args is as well. Anyways thanks this should help me get started!!

Comment: By default every line in the batch file will get echoed before it's run, `@echo off` turns this off so that the only output is what is explicitly echoed using the `echo` command. `goto :eof` is the batch equivalent of a `return` statement.

Comment: Nicely done. Quibble: using the term "`goto` labels" is a tad confusing in the context of functions (subroutines), since you use `call`, not `goto`, to invoke them; while both `goto` and `call` target a _label_, the code associated with a label must be geared to one or the other invocation method (jump-to-and-continue with `goto`, jump-to-and-return with `call`).

Comment: @mklement0, good point. Do you have any suggestions as to what I should refference the latter as? `goto` functions?

Comment: Sadly, `cmd.exe`'s command-line help doesn't give the concept a name. Personally, I would simply call them "subroutines" (that are invoked with `call`) as opposed to "functions", to emphasize that no values can be returned by them (though that distinction is fuzzy). And I'd call the target of both `goto` and `call` commands - e.g., `:func1` - simply "label". Thus, you could say: "You can also use labels to create subroutines invoked with `call`:"